# standard console input

Tags: java

Good afternoon

I would just like to know  the easiest way for standard Console input with java. 
When it come to int or double input for example in C# it is simple.
What would the easiest way be of doing this in java.?

```
double a;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value");

        a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("thank you for entering " + a);
```

Kind regards
Arian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The direct translation is:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the value");
double i = Double.parse(scan.nextLine());
System.out.println("thank you for entering " + i);
```

But you can also use [`Scanner#nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the value");
double i = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("thank you for entering " + i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String s = br.readLine();
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
      Number n = df.parse(s);
    double d = n.doubleValue();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTree();
     } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTree();
     }
```

or

```
   try {
          InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
          String s = br.readLine();
          double d = Double.parseDouble(s);

        } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTree();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTree();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `java.util.Scanner` - it has support to read numbers from STDIN.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 5.0 & above provides a feature to read input from console - Java.util.Scanner. The code below reads a String and an Integer from the console and stores them in the variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputExp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String name;
       int age;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

```
   // Reads a single line from the console 
   // and stores into name variable
   name = in.nextLine();

   // Reads a integer from the console
   // and stores into age variable
   age=in.nextInt();
   in.close();            

   // Prints name and age to the console
   System.out.println("Name :"+name);
  System.out.println("Age :"+age);
```

} }

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("Please enter the value");      
      double a = in.readDouble();
      System.console().writer().println("thank you for entering " + a);
```